# Custom Query - show first post twice?

Tags: wp-query

In a custom query, is there a way to show the first post twice? I want to show the first post in a certain format at the top of my query, then again right under it along with my other posts (maybe a little redundant). I've tried just pulling the post then showing it like, but when I call `the_post` it seems to remove it from my overall array of objects.

**Simplified Version**

```
<?php if($test->have_posts()) : $test->the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?> 

<?php if($test->have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while($test->have_posts()) : $test->the_post(); ?>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I've also tried to get into the array but I'm not sure how:

```
$post = $test->WP_Query[0];
```

How can I show my post, without 2 queries or modifying the original custom query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [rewind posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts) after the first post and run the loop again.

```
if($test->have_posts()) :
    $test->the_post();
    the_title();
endif;

$test->rewind_posts();

if($test->have_posts()) :
    while($test->have_posts()) :
        $test->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
endif;
```